# Why won't Magento connect to the local database?

Tags: mysql, xml, database, magento

I copied my company's Magento website to my local machine in order to set up a development environmnet. However, when trying to view the page at 'localhost/html', I get the following connection error:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'easyfair_eftest'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I believe this is because the username is incorrect. However, I have already modified the local.xml file to use the correct username (app/etc/local.xml). Why is it still trying to connect using the old username?

I am using WAMP for my local environment.

Comment: Change url paths in core config data table so they will point to your local url

Comment: My clean site at localhost/magento/ works perfectly, but my test production site at localhost/html/ is giving the access denied error. They boht point at the same DB. Why is the error not reflecting the local username that I input in app/etc/local.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Please try 127.0.0.1 in place of localhost.